# Can I printf as console.warn with emscripten?

Tags: c++, webassembly, emscripten

Is it possible to display a console warning, instead of a console log, from the C/C++?

So far `printf("Message")` will print on the regular `console.log` on the JS side, is it possible to print as warning like `console.warn`?

Comment: I'm guessing you want the way a browser formats warnings (as opposed to sending to `stderr` instead of `stdout`, in which case `fprintf(stderr,...`) would work)... if so, using `emscripten_run_script()` or `EM_JS()` as detailed [here](https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/Interacting-with-code.html#interacting-with-code-call-javascript-from-native) might do the trick, but I'm not in a position to test.

Answer (score 1):

In generated html file, standard output is mapped to `console.log()`.

For example

```
  var Module = {
    preRun: [],
    postRun: [],
    print: function(text) {
      if (arguments.length > 1) text = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).join(' ');
      console.warn(text);
    },
    printErr: function(text) {
      if (arguments.length > 1) text = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).join(' ');
      console.error(text);
    },
```

https://emscripten.org/docs/api_reference/module.html?highlight=stdout#Module.print